# Setup the sizing an element for different breakpoints

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I can't figure out how to set up a different width depending on a breakpoint.
For example, the following code will be applied for all the breakpoints:

```html
<nav class="navbar-nav w-75 ml-md-4">
... a select element
</nav>
```

But how to trigger `w-100` for screens larger or equal to medium ?

Answer (score 1):

The [width util classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/sizing/) are not responsive (don't have breakpoints), so you'd have to setup a custom media query...

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .w-md-100 {
     width:100% !important;
  }
}
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/p/dmGpB0YQXP

Comment: Oups, sorry, my bad, I should display it as `w-100` on small screen but `w-75` on medium and larger. So I put it as ` <nav class="navbar-nav w-md-75 w-100 mx-md-5">` and changed in css file: `@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .w-md-75 {
       width:75% !important;
    }
  }`. But it didn't work.